# Display an image using dojo programmatically

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm trying to display an image using dojo programmatically. I've tried "dijit/Dialog" and "dojox/image/Lightbox". 
When I use the Dialog the image dialog displays some characters instead of image. 
And when i Use the Lightbox, the image always displays second time.

```
imageDialog = new Dialog({
  title:  "my image",
  preload: false,
  href: "/ajax/fileStreamer"
});
imageDialog.show();
```

The above code displays only some characters. If i give a relative path to an image, the result is same.

With Lightbox, if it's relative path then image displays. But with image stream it displays on second click.

Comment: did you try to set the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightbox assumes the file is an image so adds internally the `<img />` tag to the href attribute, whereas Dialog does not, hence the need to use the content attribute including manually the `<img />` tag instead. Depending on what you wish to achieve, you have several options (increasing complexity / fancyness):

With ContentPane:

```
        require(['dijit/layout/ContentPane'], function (ContentPane) {
            var theImage = new ContentPane({content: '<img  src="yourimageurl"/>'}, 'theImage');
            theImage.startup();
        });
```

with Dialog (extends ContentPane):

```
        require(['dijit/Dialog'], function (Dialog) {
            var theImage = new Dialog({title: 'the image', content: '<img  src="yourimageurl"/>'});
            theImage.startup();
            theImage.show();
        });
```

with Lightbox (needs Lightbox css, uses LightboxDialog internally which extends Dialog):

```
        require(['dojox/image/Lightbox'], function (Lightbox) {
            var theImage = new Lightbox({title: 'the image', href: 'yourimageurl'});
            theImage.startup();
            theImage.show();
        });
```

with LightboxDialog (idem Lightbox, exposes the LightboxDialog instance):

```
        require(['dojox/image/Lightbox'], function (Lightbox) {
            var theDialog = new dojox.image.LightboxDialog({});
            theDialog.startup();
            theDialog.show({title: 'the image', href: 'yourimageurl'});
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Add your image html markup within the `content` property of your [dialog](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Dialog.html).

Live example:

```js
require([
  'dojo/domReady!'
], function() {
  require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog, Button) {
    var myDialog = new Dialog({
      title: "Programmatic Dialog Creation",
      style: "width: 300px"
    });

    var myButton = new Button({
      label: "Show me!",
      onClick: function() {
        myDialog.set("content", '<img class="lightbox-image" style="" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">' + new Date() + "!");
        myDialog.show();
      }
    }, "progbutton");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />

<script>
  window.dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: false,
    async: true
  };
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js">
</script>

<body class="claro">
  <p>When pressing this button the dialog will popup. Notice this time there is no DOM node with content for the dialog:</p>
  <button id="progbutton" type="button">Show me!</button>
</body>
```